# When is modifier noun in plural?

Tags: nouns, plural-forms, modifiers

Why isn't "store" in the plural in the sentence below?

> More than 7,400 **store** closures have been announced this year

The sentence is from Financial Times.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the noun isn't 'store', the noun is '**store closure**'.

The author is not talking about the stores themselves, but is referring to the fact that they are closing.

Comment: typically when a noun modifies another noun which is plural, we don't pluralize the modifier noun just to match: "car doors", "kitchen knives", "bottle caps", etc